# Ошибка: Доменный пароль просрочен и должен быть заменен при входе по смарт-карте

Tags: windows, домен, active-directory

Кто знает как связаться со службой поддержки microsoft?

Или может кто подскажет как самому исправить проблему:
Если доменный пароль просрочен и пользователь входит в компьютер по смарт-карте, то Windows выдаст ошибку "Пароль просрочен и должен быть заменен" далее появится кнопка "ОК" и при нажатии на неё  появляется только кнопка "Отмена", а кнопка "ОК" отсутствует. А по правильному винда должна была предложить изменить доменный пароль. Пользователей в домене более 5000, поэтому склоняюсь к том что нужен патч.

Офф тех.поддержка с майкрософтом отсутствует в связи с внесением организации в санкционный  список.
Помогите избавиться от десятка однотипных звонков пользователей. Инструкции для пользователей тоже имеются и рассылаются каждый месяц, но у людей, вышедших из продолжительного отпуска, форматируется мозг наглухо.

Comment: Действительно ли используются карты и какое приложение используется для аутентификации? Попытайтесь сбросить пароль на клавиатурный с заменой при первом входе на аутентификацию по карте... Аналогичные проблемы у нас довольно часто бывают при использовании ТМ

Comment: Что значит "Действительно ли используются карты"? В домене на всех ПК установлен запрет на "вход не по смарт-карте". 
Для аутентификации установлен SafeNet. В домене можно авторизовываться как по логину и паролю, так и и по смарт-карте, но пустит в ПК на только по смарт-карте.

Comment: Просто о реальном использовании карт ни разу не слышал, хотя о доменной ф-ции знаю.

Comment: имеются какие-либо результаты? Чем победили?

Comment: увы нет :( ищу...

Comment: Пробуйте по поменять дату в Биос Через командную строку cmd
Net accounts
Далее разбираюсь сам. Ведь , максимальный срок действия пароля не изменяется
(Ноут был без пароля)

Comment: Так потому и не выводит смену пароля поскольку _запрет на "вход не по смарт-карте"_. Можно поставить пользователю в АД "срок действия пароля не ограничен" либо изменить срок действия пароля для всех через политики, раз уж все равно использование пароля запрещено и заботиться о его надежности нет смысла